# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling class init in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've been trying to figure this out but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I wrote a class and whenever I try to initialize it, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I can't even step into the initialization.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
User *myUser = [myUser init];
```

.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface User : NSObject {
    long rowId;
    NSString *email;
    NSString *password;
    NSString *fileVersion;
}

@property long rowId;
@property (assign) NSString *email;
@property (assign) NSString *password;
@property (assign) NSString *fileVersion;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "User.h"


@implementation User

@synthesize rowId, email, password, fileVersion;

-(id)init {

    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Be sure to understand what’s an _assign_ property and why it’s not common for NSString* properties to be _assign_ (hint: they’re usually _copy_).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to actually allocate the object:

```
User *myUser = [[User alloc] init];
```

Don't forget to `release` it when you're done using it.

Comment: Or `autorelease` it upon allocation (in which case, it's usual to write a helper class method that does the `alloc`/`init`/`autorelease`).

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping it was something obvious.